# Get data having a maximum attribute from firebase in nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So i am working with firebase in nodejs, there is a "number" attribute in each of my document of a specific table(name generated at runtime). I want to get the data having the attribute "number"'s maximum value.

Here is my sample data:-

```
    -L1GIb7Vyn6Yhd5gghH0

    correct: blah

    number: 9

    question: A sample question

    wrong1:  blekh

    wrong2:  blahhh
```

I have seen answers like "childAdded" and all but all in vain also I can't use .endAt() or startAt() because I don't know the "number"'s value at any time.

My sample code till now is:-

```
queRef.child(req.session.quiztopicname+req.session.quiztopictype).
    orderByChild("number").endAt(9).once("value",function(snapshot){
console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [limitToLast(1)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#limitToLast) on your sorted reference/query to only retrieve the greatest value.  Bear in mind that if there are multiple children with the same greatest value, you'll still only get one of them.  There's more documentation or sorting and filtering [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data).